# nginx ingress controller type nlb with static ip giving error "AllocationIdNotFound"

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, nlb

I am creating nginx ingress controller of type nlb with static ips, but for static ips I am getting this error `AllocationIdNotFound`. Although this allocation id is valid and eip with this id is present in the same region.
Here are the annotations that I am using with nginx ingress controller service

```
annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets: "subnet-xxxxxxxxxx, subnet-xxxxxxxxxx"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations: "eipalloc-xxxxxxxxxx, eipalloc-xxxxxxxxxx"
```

If I comment `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations` annotation, load balancer gets created successfully but without eips.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Try add this annotation: `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing`

Comment: Did you see [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/APIReference/API_SetSubnets.html)?

Comment: @gohm'c I also tried with this, but no success

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, I have just encountered the same issue.

There seems to be a bug in the way the service interprets the `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations` annotation. If you remove the space after the comma it should work.

Try this:

```yaml
annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets: "subnet-xxxxxxxxxx, subnet-xxxxxxxxxx"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations: "eipalloc-xxxxxxxxxx,eipalloc-xxxxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: Thanks you, I just had this same issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually create eips either through cli or console and add there allocation id as comma separated in the annotation, it'll get created. Make sure to have same number of subnets and eips as your availability zones.